# Starting X-server with different configs for different seats with gdm3

Tags: xorg, gdm, multiseat, spice

I have PC with two video cards.
I want to use multiseat:

- 1 seat is local
- 2 seat is remote (with `xserver-xspice` package)

There is no problems with `lightdm` display manager, i can specify x-server config for each seat in lightdm config file (first is default, second is special xorg.conf which starts spice-server).

**Is there way to use multiseat with different xorg configs for `gdm3` display manager?**

The problem is that second X-server has virtual devices (screen, keyboard, mouse), X-server emulates them with spice drivers, and emulating starts with X-server. So, i can't attach this devices to second seat.

The reason i need 2 X-servers is because using X-server in spice mode blocks local graphic session (i can see only black screen).